# Is there a way to define common relationship filters in Entity Framework Core?

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core

Say I have a relationship defined as:

```
public class Report {
  public bool Approved { get; set; }
}

public class FileCabinet {
  public List<Report> Reports { get; set; }
  [NotMapped]
  public IEnumerable<Report> ApprovedReports => Reports.Where(x => x.Approved);
}
```

`ApprovedReports` is unmapped and cannot be used in database queries but it does locally filter the results from the database. I would like to define the filter in such a way that is can be used in Linq queries to the database instead of a developer having to use `.Where(x => x.Approved)`. Is there a way to map this property or define filters in EF Core? To be clear this is not a global filter.  This is a common filter that some queries would use and others would not.

Answer (score 1):

Not on the Entity itself because it has no reference to the DbContext, and `Reports` is a collection, not a query.  You could put a method on the DbContext

```
IQueryable<FileCabinet> FileCabinetWithApprovedReports => this.FileCabinets.Include( f => f.Reports.Where( r => r.Approved) );
```

To which you could compose additional query expressions.

Or add a [Global Query Filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/filters#:%7E:text=Global%20query%20filters%20are%20LINQ%20query%20predicates%20applied,to%20any%20LINQ%20queries%20involving%20those%20Entity%20Types.) to make Approved reports the default.